# Batch calculation of dataframe cells based on values from two other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Based on a first dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(1), freq='D')
symbols = ['A','B']
np.random.seed(seed=1111)
dataA = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
dataB = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({symbols[0]: dataA,symbols[1] :dataB },index=days)
print(df1)
                             A   B
2019-05-20 06:52:21.013198  29  82
2019-05-21 06:52:21.013198  56  13
```

and a second dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'const1': [1,2],'const2' : [2,3] },index=['A','B'])
print(df2)
   const1  const2
A       1       2
B       2       3
```

I want to calculate a third dataframe with the same structure as the first dataframe, where each cell is the result of a calculation combining values of the first two dataframes.

The following code calculates each cell of the 3rd dataframe correctly:

```
df3 = df1
for symbol in symbols:
    const1 = df2.at[symbol,'const1']
    const2 = df2.at[symbol,'const2']
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        value = df1.at[index,symbol] 
        df3.at[index,symbol] = const1*value + const2*value
print(df3)
                              A    B
2019-05-20 06:58:52.753879   87  410
2019-05-21 06:58:52.753879  168   65
```

How can I get rid of the ugly loops and do that calculation more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
df3 = df1 * df2.sum(axis=1)
```

And now:

```
print(df3)
```

Is:

```
                              A    B
2019-05-20 06:58:52.753879   87  410
2019-05-21 06:58:52.753879  168   65
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible some symbols not match:

```
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(1), freq='D')
symbols = ['A','C']
np.random.seed(seed=1111)
dataA = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
dataB = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({symbols[0]: dataA,symbols[1] :dataB },index=days)
print(df1)
                             A   C
2019-05-20 09:24:33.383637  29  82
2019-05-21 09:24:33.383637  56  13

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'const1': [1,2],'const2' : [2,3] },index=['A','B'])
print(df2)
   const1  const2
A       1       2
B       2       3
```

---

```
df3 = df1.mul(df2.sum(axis=1).reindex(df1.columns, fill_value=1))
print (df3)
                              A   C
2019-05-20 09:25:48.075084   87  82
2019-05-21 09:25:48.075084  168  13
```

Because:

```
df3 = df1.mul(df2.sum(axis=1), fill_value=1)
```

> NotImplementedError: fill_value 1 not supported.